# Logic Error In a Random Color Picking Guessing Game

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to make a program that displays an `RGB value`, representing a color, and asks the user to guess which color matches said RGB value from 9 squares.

[Here is a more (advanced) version of how it should work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO5ZG.gif) My problem so far is that there is a logic error in my code that I have not been able to fix. Most of the time 9 randomly colored squares are generated and I am able to click on them until I am able to guess the correspondingly colored square, and the game ends. However, occasionally, I click on all the squares and nothing occurs.

I have read over my code dozens of times, and am unsure where the error comes from, as sometimes it works just as it should logically, and others it simply does not.

```
//Array that contains 9 randomly generated colors. Values in the array will be generated by colorListGeneratior()

var colors =[];
var numOfColors= 9;
colorListGenerator();

var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var pickedColor = pickedColor(colors);
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++)
{

    //Add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor= colors[i];

    //Change color of each square on click
    squares[i].addEventListener("click",function()
    {

        var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        if(clickedColor==pickedColor){
            messageDisplay.textContent ="Correct!";
            changeColors(clickedColor)
            h1.style.color=clickedColor;
         }

         else{
             messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again!";
             this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
         }
    });
}

//Changes all color of all the squares to the correctly picked color.

function changeColors(color){

    for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

//Assigns variables r,g,b each a random value from 0 to 255. Returns a //string representing an rgb color in the form "rgb(r_value,g_value,b_value)".

function colorGenerator(){

    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var color = "rgb("+ r +", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

    return color

}

//Creates a list of 9 colors each in the form of "rgb(r_value,g_value,b_value)"

function colorListGenerator()
{
    for(var j=0;j<numOfColors;j++){
    colors.push(colorGenerator());}
}


//Chooses a random color from the list of randomly generated colors, to be the goal color.

function pickedColor(colorsList)
{
    randomIndexPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * numOfColors);
    pickedColor = colorsList[randomIndexPosition];

    return pickedColor
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should describe what exactly you want to achieve. I bet very few people here know what is the "Colt Steele Web Developer Bootcamp Color Game Project". And format your code also.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to StackOverflow! Do you see any errors in your browser console when using this? Also, it may help people debug & answer your question if you provide all your HTML & JS

Comment: How many `square` do you have in you HTML? If you have less than 9, the chosen color might not be printed out, hence even after click all the squares, you still can't finish the game.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone... turns out my variable that stored the number of squares that I had, had the value of 9 when I only had 6 squares. So anytime one of the winning colors were stored in my colors list from index positions 6-8, they would simply be out of range for my code that checked if one of the chosen squares was correctly picked, as my code in this case only took into elements from 0 to 5. A very simple error that you correctly pointed out Hp93, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I got bored and haven't written much HTML / JS for a while so decided to have a play around!

You had a few minor JS issues related to naming of your variables and functions, as well as a couple of scoping problems which could have caused the behaviour you described.

Updated JS snippet is here for you.

```js
//Array that contains 9 randomly generated colors. Values in the array will be generated by colorListGeneratior()

var colors = [];
var numOfColors = 9;
colorListGenerator();

var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var pickedColor = pickColor(colors);
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

  //Add initial colors to squares
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

  //Change color of each square on click
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    if (clickedColor == pickedColor) {
      messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct!";
      changeColors(clickedColor)
      h1.style.color = clickedColor;
    } else {
      messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again!";
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
    }
  });
}

//Changes all color of all the squares to the correctly picked color.

function changeColors(color) {

  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

//Assigns variables r,g,b each a random value from 0 to 255. Returns a //string representing an rgb color in the form "rgb(r_value,g_value,b_value)".

function colorGenerator() {

  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var color = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

  return color

}

//Creates a list of 9 colors each in the form of "rgb(r_value,g_value,b_value)"

function colorListGenerator() {
  for (var j = 0; j < numOfColors; j++) {
    colors.push(colorGenerator());
  }
}


//Chooses a random color from the list of randomly generated colors, to be the goal color.

function pickColor(colorsList) {
  randomIndexPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * numOfColors);
  return colorsList[randomIndexPosition];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Squares</title>
  <style>
    .square {
      width: 33%;
      height: 50px;
      float: left
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Squares</h1>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div id="colorDisplay"></div>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <input type="submit" id="reset" value="Reset">
</body>

</html>
```